# SQL - Syncing Denormalize Table

Tags: mysql, sql, denormalization

I have a `USERS` table and a `LOGS` table. The `LOGS` table was normalized, storing only a `user_id` until recently, when I decided to denormalized it for performance reasons. After this change, I have `username` and `user_role` columns as part of `LOGS` table as well.

Now I need to update existing records of the `LOGS` table to fill out `username` and `user_role` columns, based on the value of `user_id` column, so that data becomes consistent. How can go about achieving this? I'm looking for possibly an SQL script that I can run on the database server.

Asim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this. You can just join the users table

```
UPDATE LOGS l
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id=l.user_id
SET l.username=u.name,
  l.user_role=u.role
WHERE ... if necessary
```

UPDATE:

```
UPDATE LOGS l
INNER JOIN (select l.id as log_id, u.*
            from logs l join users u ON u.id=l.user_id
            order by l.id
            limit 10) sub ON sub.id=l.id
SET l.username=sub.name,
  l.user_role=sub.role
```

Comment: a follow up question.. i noticed that the sql `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses dont work with this type of query (update + join).. it works with a standard or joined `SELECT` query.. how can i impose a `LIMIT` with this query?

Comment: it works yes.. however if i wish to limit and order based on the `LOGS` table, the `LOGS` table becomes a read-only view.. and updating fails..

Comment: hmm... actually you can JOIN (select LOGS.id as logs_id, * from LOGS join users ) sub ON sub.log_id=l.id

Comment: im sorry but im unable to get it to work, would you be kind enough to lay out the complete query? i need to update the `LOGS` table in batches of X rows while joining it with other tables.. heres my query right now..

`UPDATE LOGS l
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = l.user_id
SET
l.username = u.username,
l.user_role = u.user_role
WHERE
l.username IS NULL`

Comment: works like a charm.. and i also understand how it works and why.. thank you so much.. :)